# iOS Custom Button Gray Box when tapped

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I have a custom button that has an image
When the user taps (and holds) on the button - iOS displays a gray box around the button that looks very ugly.  How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed it is highlighted - 
Unchecking the "Highlighted Adjusts Image" fixes the problem